# How the return result like this , What is the lambda function do in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
flist = []

for i in range(3):

    flist.append(lambda: i)

for f in flist:
    print f()
```

I don't know why its returning 2,2,2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last iteration through the first loop, your `i` value is 2 and hence ALL the `i` values in each element of the list are now 2. This is because you have created a live reference to the `i` variable.

Here is a simplified demonstration:

```
a = 5
c = lambda: a
a += 5
>>> c()
10
```

Comment: laziness works against intuition in this particular case :)